# Ajax Infinite scroll doesn't works with mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile, infinite-scroll

I made a infinite scroll script on my website using php, mysql, ajax and jQuery which work perfectly. However it doesn't work on mobiles phones. I tried to download infinite scroll plugins to see how they do to make it work on mobiles but my skills are to low to determine which part are useful for me.

Here is the JS code.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            
$.ajax({
       url : "load.php?lastv=" + $("img:last").attr('alt'),
       success : function(html){
                if(html){
            $('.display-bg').append(html);
            }else{
                alert('no more post');
            }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: in which event this code is??